# How to convert date into other format in moment.js using KnockoutJs Binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, momentjs, bootstrap-datepicker

In my web application I use Bootstrap-datepicker-and-KnockoutJs Binding for date, How can I convert the date into other format?

```
self.date = ko.observable(moment())
                        .extend({ required: true });
```

Default it shows

> Thu Aug 06 2015 11:59:21 GMT+0530

after datepicker it shows

> Thu Aug 06 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

trying to convert this value to other

```
moment(self.date, '2015-08-06T011:32:21.196Z')
```

it shows

> Invalid date

Here I use knockout binding shows below

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
    $(element).datepicker(options).on("changeDate", function (ev) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable(ev.date);
    });
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).datepicker("setValue", value);
}
};
```

How I do this, Is this a proper way? suggest a solution,
Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a custom binding implementation for KnockoutJS with MomentJS

https://github.com/adrotec/knockout-date-bindings

Another option is to define `ko.computed()` which will use timestamp as dependent variable

```js
var Vm = function() {
      var self = this;
      
      self.date = ko.observable();
      self.dateFormatted = ko.computed(function() {
        return moment(self.date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")
      });
      
      setInterval(function() {
        self.date(new Date());
      }, 1000);
    };
    
    var vm = new Vm();
    ko.applyBindings(vm, $("body")[0]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="knockout@3.3.0" data-semver="3.3.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="moment.js@2.10.2" data-semver="2.10.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 data-bind="text: dateFormatted"></h1>
    <script>
    var Vm = function() {
      var self = this;
      
      self.date = ko.observable();
      self.dateFormatted = ko.computed(function() {
        return moment(self.date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")
      });
      
      setInterval(function() {
        self.date(new Date());
      }, 1000);
    };
    
    var vm = new Vm();
    ko.applyBindings(vm, $("body")[0]);
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```